# Intel AMT bug ? ( When client enable the “Allow the device to wake the computer” )

Tags: windows, bios, remote-access, intel-core-i7, intel-amt

There are two methods can wake up the client device from S3/S4 by server side device: ( client and server in same LAN )

1.
Use the "Wake on LAN" which is enabling the option "Allow the device to wake the computer" ( In my client device , it supports PCIE WAKE# technology )

[image]

2.
Use the Intel AMT technology which providing WebUI to control the remotely wake up the client device from S3/S4.

[image]

In my experiments:

When client enabling the option "Allow the device to wake the computer" ( Device Manager --> Wireless device --> right click --> Power Management ) and Intel AMT together , server can wake up the client from S3/S4 even if just login the WebUI. ( No need to use the "Remote Control interface" in WebUI )

I want to know that this strange situation is correct ? Is it the Intel AMT bug ? When i just only login the WebUI , the PCIE wake up package also sending to the client device?

Comment: " Is it the Intel AMT bug?" - What exactly do you believe is a bug?

Comment: The capabilities of AMT are separate that of the Wake On Lan feature of your WAN adapter.

Comment: I have got the intel reply , they said the Intel AMT also package the wake on lan message even if  just using the WebUI.

Comment: You should submit an answer instead of a comment that cannot be upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I got the confirmation from Intel , they said this is expected behavior in S3 when system is provisioned and ME WLAN enabled.

In the WoWLAN scenario , AMT's traffic will add as the wakeup pattern , and this will casue auto wake up ( because user also enable Wake on Lan in device manager ) even if user just only do the login action by AMT WebUI tool.